# Convert from in-app to paid application

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I was wondering if someone has experience in converting a free app with an in-app that unlocks the full version to a paid version.

Is there any way to check at runtime that the user has paid for the in-app?

Comment: Are you trying to detect if a user hasn't unlocked the features so that you can deny them the unlock in the new, paid, version? If so, how do they unlock the features if they want to?

Comment: You can just unlock all features by default, and remove in-app purchase. Then change the app's price from 'free' to any price that you want. The only problem is that all users that have already downloaded your app before will get full functionality without paying. But that is the only way that I see in this situation, unless you release it as a new app with different bundle id.

Comment: @almas, that's the path I am going to roll if I don't figure something. I wouldn't want the users that downloaded the free version of the app and have not purchased the in-app to have access to the full version. Therefore I can leave the in-app button for them. If I see that a user has already purchased the in-app in an older version, then I unlock the full version.

Comment: You want the user to do an in-app purchase to unlock your app? You should read Apple's docs on in-app purchases. There are also a lot of tutorials on how to implement this.

Tutorial
http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_In-App_Purchase_Tutorial

Apple's Docs
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html

Comment: @JustinHolman, thanks, but that's not what I'm asking about. I want the users that haven't unlocked the full version, keep their lite version even after I updated the price from free to paid.

Comment: I see a couple of options. 1) Release an update that sets a flag, probably NSUserDefaults that they have the lite version. (If they reinstall, this would disappear and they would have. 2) If you have a login system, add a boolean for if that user is lite vs paid. 3) Like the others said, a new app id would solve this. Then you either keep updating both, or have to decided an EOL plan. 4) Add the in app purchase capability. Have you thought how existing users will be able to purchase?

Comment: @JustinHolman, I was thinking of a plan like this: 1) make the app paid 2) existing users that have not paid will have the option to buy the full version through in-app or if they re-install the app and purchase the paid version from the App Store 3) existing users that bought the in-app will also keep the full version. So I need a 100% sure method to check that they have already bought the in-app. I can check the in-app purchase date and the first install date, but I don't know how to get the first install of the app date.

Comment: The only way this will work is to release a new version with a new bundle id and make that paid. For instant com.your company.myapp2 Existing users keep the same one they have and they buy your new version and new users buy it as well. You cannot just enable the features and make it a paid app because existing free users will get those updates. Now you could just update it with the features unlocked, but make it paid and all existing users get it for free as a thank you.